# php ajax refresh part of page on click

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, refresh

I want to be able to click on a link lower down my PHP page, it send a variable and outputs the result in a `<div>` tag at the top half of the page.

I've linked to latest jquery, and so far I have this in my `<head>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $().ready(function() {
   $("#result").load("crimes_result.php");
   });
</script>
```

And in my `<body>`:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

What I need though, is that the div to be shown and depending on the result of a variable sent by a link the user clicks lower down the page.

like `crimes_result.php?id=4334` or `crimes_result.php?id=54543`

How can I finish my script so it does that?

NOTE: I'm useless in ajax/jquery/javascript

Comment: Doesn't the focus event in JavaScript do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, simply call `.load()` from a click event and pass it the href of the link:

HTML:

`<a class="loadlink" href="crimes_result.php?id=4334">Click Me<a>`

JS:

```
$(".loadlink").click( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#result").load($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/ueucL/1/

Comment: When I click the link in that, it's going to crimes_result.php instead of just refreshing the div with the result of crimes_result.php

Comment: Did you add `event.preventDefault();` and make sure you have `function(event){` ?

Comment: yeah i've now got what I posted in the question, plus added this code what you suggested.